# MNIST dataset conversion

Tags: python, image

[image: Trained image] I've trained a decision tree on a dataset (handwritten) which contains 8 x-y points sampled along the length of the number (number digit dataset). The test dataset given (assignment), is the MNIST dataset, which is the pixel intensities in a 28x28 bitmap image. I need to sample 8 points and along the trajectory of the number so that it performs well.

I'm doing this in Python. I don't know what to do with the image to sample those points. Any package/procedure will help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'along the length of the number' or 'along the trajectory of the number'? A picture would help. You can get the middle (ish) row of a 28 x 28 array like `arr[14]`... but I doubt that's what you mean?

Comment: I've added an image. As you can see, those 8 points are my training examples. However, I need to test it on the mnist data, which isn't like the training example. Is there a way to convert between them?

Answer (score 1):

Simply index the array as you would any other array. The pixel intensities are merely ints.  e.g val = arr[3,9].

Comment: I've added an image. As you can see, those 8 points are my training examples. However, I need to test it on the mnist data (only pixel intensities), which isn't like the training example. Is there a way to convert between them?

Comment: Basically convert between mnist data (pixel intensities) to this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnBXM.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to training the 8 points in your picture against the the 5's in the MNIST sample? And then do that for each number (1-9)?

Comment: I took 5 as an example here. My Decision tree is trained against the 8 points (16x1 maritx). I need to run it against the mnist data (each row is 784x1 which is a 28x28 image really). Therefore, I need to find some way to extract 8 points along the direction of the letter(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnBXM.jpg) when all I have is pixel values(mnist data is represented that way)

Comment: I think I understand now. I think you are going to have to do that manually, or develop a model to do that for you, which kind of makes the original objective redundant as far as I can see.

Comment: Doing that manually is not an option. There are too many data points to do that for. 
That makes sense, but that's the assignment I've been given.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the stroke direction in mnist.
Hence, you cannot reliably infer such positions.

You can do the opposite though: render the stroke information as pixel image, train a classifier on that, and then test it with mnist.

Answer (score 1):

There's an **MNIST sequence dataset** from Edwin de Jong:

- Paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.03068.pdf
- Github: https://edwin-de-jong.github.io/blog/mnist-sequence-data/
- Blog: https://github.com/edwin-de-jong/mnist-digits-as-stroke-sequences/

and an **MNIST classification using RNN** by Ryan Epp:

- https://www.ryanepp.com/blog/mnist-classification-using-stroke-paths

In both projects, the direction strokes will take at a T-junction depends on the algorithm and is often counterintuitive. This means that there's more to learn for sequences since many stroke patterns will produce the same image.

[image: digit 4 as a sequence]